# Facebook Security Warning when customers click through to website

Tags: facebook

I have a website (www.oatmama.com).  When users click from our Facebook page to our website, there is the following security error, and when trying to click through on mobile, they are prevented from doing so.

**The warning that we get:**

```
Something went wrong. Sorry, there was a problem with this link: 
http://www.oatmama.com/ You can now continue to this website, or 
go back to the page you were on before. Remember, only follow 
links from sources you trust."
```

Any insight into what this error means and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that facebook had a problem with my `.htaccess` file trying to rewrite my `http://` urls as `https://`

Once I removed those lines the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Your security setting needs to be updated. Once you do that it should fix your problems.

You can run your website through the Facebook Debugger by following this link: [https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?ref=u2u](https://www.facebook.com/login.php?next=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Ftools%2Fdebug%2F%3Fref%3Du2u)

Once you've done so, you'll be able to see any errors that Facebook is reading from your website. I would recommend seeking help from Facebook Developers in order to make your website compliant so their systems will detect it as safe. You can reach out to them by opening this link: https://developers.facebook.com/tools-and-support/?ref=u2u. You'll need to click "Get Started" and follow the instructions to open a support ticket.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  We are looking into this, but in the meantime, there is no "Get Started" button on https://developers.facebook.com/tools-and-support/?ref=u2u

Comment: Kamal...thanks again for the answer.  I am completely new here, and thus my lack of reputation points prevents me from attaching an image, but we see a very different security message.  (1) Identity verified ,(2) verified by COMODO RSA Extended Validation Secure Server CA and is publicly auditable (Certificate and Transparency links follow, and (3) connection is encrypted with modern cryptology.  Would you mind checking again to see if you still come up with the same?

Comment: Hey Alan.. Yes I am still seeing the same thing as my above screenshot.. And on the facebook developers screen click your picture on the top right and click requests. There you can make a request for a facebook developer to help you out.

Comment: Thank you again, Kamal...I am very confused because this is not at all what I nor my partners see.  The problem with the Facebook Developers screen is that this group is for those creating apps and without an app in creation/process, there is no way for me to make a request.